# PositionChanged event not triggered in Windows 8 store app using xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

In the  below code the event PositionChanged is never fired .I am trying to execute this code in my laptop.Is there way to check if the GPS is available in the device before I execute any code .

```
private async void Track_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        locator = new Geolocator();
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
        locator.MovementThreshold = 10;
        locator.ReportInterval = 2000;
        locator.PositionChanged += locator_PositionChanged;
        locator.PositionChanged +=  new TypedEventHandler<Geolocator, PositionChangedEventArgs>(OnPositionChanged);


    }

    void locator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void OnPositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {

        dAltitude = Convert.ToDouble( args.Position.Coordinate.Altitude.ToString());
        dPrevLongitude = Convert.ToDouble(args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString());
        dPrevLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved after enabling internet capabilities.